# MKMapView Memory Leak

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, mkmapview, automatic-ref-counting

I've got a problem with memory leaks in my use of MKMapView. The MKMapView itself is deallocated, but some other objects like MKTileView, MKMapTileViewImp, and MKTiledLayer don't get destroyed and end up recreated and leaking.

I've reproduced the effect in a simple piece of code

```
@implementation ViewController
{
    MKMapView * mapView;
}


- (void)leak:(id)sender
{
    [mapView removeFromSuperview];
    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(20, 20, 20, 20)];
    [self.view addSubview: mapView];
}
```

Everytime the button hooked up to leak is pushed, a new instance of MKTileView gets leaked.

I'm using ARC. I've looked at the other questions, but none seem to mention the same leaks that I'm seeing here.

Any ideas what my problem might be?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code. Most likely MKMapView is keeping around a cache of objects that appears like a leak. I wouldn't lose any sleep over it unless it gets really out of hand, using up megabytes of RAM. UIWebView has similar issues.

Comment: @EricS, I'd have thought that. But if I keep push the button (or opening/closing a window in my app) there seems to be no limit to how many objects there ends up being.

Comment: @WinstonEwert Have you solved your problem? I'm having the same problem here (iOS > 6) ;)

Comment: @HAS, I've long since ceased to work on that project, but I never was able to eliminate the leak.